# xampp apache perl module not found

Tags: perl, apache, webserver, xampp

i have a problem with my apache server in xampp.  when i want to start it my xampp log says this:

```
Busy...
Apache started [port 80]
```

But it does in fact nothing but apache starting and after a second or 2 it just stops itself  and if i check my error.log from my apache server it gives the following error:

`[Mon Mar 18 15:46:28 2013] [error] Can't locate XML/Simple.pm in @INC (@INC contains: C:/xampp/perl/lib C:/xampp/perl/site/lib . C:/xampp/apache) at (eval 19) line 3.\n

[Mon Mar 18 15:46:28 2013] [error] Can't load Perl module XML::Simple for server localhost:80, exiting...`
does anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: It says it doesn't have XML::Simple installed. You should install it. Depending which distribution of Perl for Windows you are using (ActivePerl or Strawberry, for example), refer to the documentation or  do a quick search.

Comment: its ok now, i just installed the newest version  of xampp and it just worked fine for me

Comment: Fair enough. Please answer your own question and mark the answer as accepted. See the [faq] how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's ok now, see my earlier response for further explanation